# How to show numeric, alphanumeric and character from a given string in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle19c

I want to show,

1. *OraCleG*
2. *10*
3. *@#$%*

from the string **"OraCle@10#$G%"** in three different rows using oracle SQL code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions might be one option:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'OraCle@10#$G%' from dual)
  3  select regexp_replace(col, '[^[:alpha:]]') letters,
  4         regexp_replace(col, '[^[:digit:]]') digits,
  5         regexp_replace(col, '[[:alnum:]]')  the_rest
  6  from test
  7  /

LETTERS DIGITS     THE_REST
------- ---------- ----------
OraCleG 10         @#$%

SQL>
```

---

If it *must* be 3 rows, then `UNION` them:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'OraCle@10#$G%' from dual)
  3  select regexp_replace(col, '[^[:alpha:]]') value from test
  4  union all
  5  select regexp_replace(col, '[^[:digit:]]')       from test
  6  union all
  7  select regexp_replace(col, '[[:alnum:]]')        from test;

VALUE
-------
OraCleG
10
@#$%

SQL>
```